# How the g++ optimization level affects the printf() in Multi-threaded programs?

Tags: multithreading, optimization, g++, printf

I Encountered a difficulty about the printf()‘s behavior in Multi-threaded Webserver program.

When I set the optimization level = "-O0",the defaule level. Printf() always not work in the new threads(at least I cannot see the output in my terminal).But in the main thread, it work well;

However, if I set the optimization level = "-O1" or "-O2".Printf() work as I expected in all threads, they print some information when the thread switch.

Are there some underlying secrets?

Codes are here: https://github.com/liwook/CPPServer/tree/main/code/server_v12.
You can Change the line 71 of Makefile to “CPPFLAGS += -fno-strict-aliasing” to see the difference.

Also, I tried some methods，such as set noblocking, fflush(stdout), and replace printf() with write().Those ways not work until I set the optimization level.

Comment: It's difficult to say without some example code for your problem. However, in general, it's not unusual for higher optimization levels to expose underlying undefined behaviour issues: the fact that it *appears* to work in your `-O0` case may just be 'luck'.